# Building Stacking machine learning model using three base classifiers

Tags: python, ensemble-modeling

I did a stacking using three base classifiers RF, NB, KN N and metamodel random forest or SVM using sklearn library

But which is strange each time i change the metamodel i got the same results. Is it normal ?????

Comment: @SeanOwen may you advise to free the question it is an intersiting question and i gave all details

Comment: I don't mind reopening it; it's borderline. Really it's better to boil this down to the essential piece of code you're asking about, and give more detail about what you have observed, narrowing it down further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i found it an interesting question about a stacking principle and it is not about code So i put all the details and explanation as required with an example with iris dataset no further  details to add thanks for your kind support i see people here evaluate the effort of others without even asking i asked to demand explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in generally speaking, even minor changes should affect your performance. Changing your meta-model should normally have a visible impact in your model's performance.

Two things you can try:

- Check for any problems in your code.
- Maybe your test set size is really small. For example if you have 5 test samples, it isn't difficult for all models to get 4/5 (i.e. 80% accuracy). As your test size increases so should the variance of your models' performance.